# Prove the sequence $(\cos(\frac{n\pi}{3}))_{n=1}^\infty$ does not converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

How would I be able to prove that $(\cos(\frac{n\pi}{3}))_{n=1}^\infty$ does not converge?

I know that for a sequence to converge to a limit, then for all $\varepsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathrm N \Rightarrow |a_n-L| < \varepsilon$. But I'm not sure how to even apply it to this problem to prove by way of contradiction.

Can someone help me write it out and explain how it doesn't converge? An help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you should write out the first few values of $\cos\left(\dfrac{n\pi}3\right)$ to give you an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subsequences $x_{6n} = \cos(6n\pi/3) \to  1$, and $x_{6n+3} = \cos ((6n+3)\pi/3 )\to -1$, so the sequence is not convergent.